# Correct notation for inequality equation

Tags: inequality, notation, quadratics

I'm currently taking a Polynomial functions -course and learning about quadratic inequality equations.

Let's consider this equation:

$-x^{2}+7x<10$

The correct answer to this according to our book is simply

> $x<2$ or $x>5$

But is there any other way to express this in a more mathematical way? I understand why this is expressed the way it is as we haven't learned about set theory yet, but I'd like to know how it is expressed "correctly".

Comment: $x\in{}\mathbb{R}/[2,5]$

Comment: $x\in \mathbb R\setminus [2,\,5]$ or, equivalently, $x\in(-\infty,\,2)\cup(5,\,+\infty)$

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll go with $x\in \mathbb{R} \backslash \left[ 2,5\right]$ as it's very simple and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as
$$x \in (-\infty,2)\cup(5,\infty)$$
or $$ x\in R - [2, 5]$$
or $$ x \in \{x: x < 2, x > 5, x\in R\}$$

See set notation for more details:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/set-builder-notation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write $\{x:x>5~~ \text{or} ~~~x<2\}$